# Closing an SQLObject Connection

Tags: python, sqlobject

Is it possible to manually close an SQLObject Connection once it has been opened?  I am trying to delete a database file once it has been used, but it seems that the open connection to the database file is stopping me from doing so.

For example:

```
from sqlobject import *
import os

# Create and open connection to a database file.
sqlhub.processConnection = connectionForURI('sqlite:path_to_db')
SomeObject.createTable()

# ...

# Delete database when finished.
os.remove('path_to_db')
```

Gives the following error:

```
WindowsError: [Error 32] The process cannot access the file because 
              it is being used by another process: 'path_to_db'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like just calling `.close()` on the database connection seems to do the trick:

```
from sqlobject import *
import os

# Create and open connection to a database file.
sqlhub.processConnection = connectionForURI('sqlite:path_to_db')

#do something with connection
pass

#close connection
sqlhub.processConnection.close()

#delete database
os.remove(path_to_db)
```

I could only find a little bit on the `close` method [here](http://www.sqlobject.org/SQLObject.html), but it's fair to say you can treat it like any other `file` object. I don't have much experience with `sqlobject` though, and in the interpreter, you can still remove the db right after the `processConnection` assignment, without closing it, so who knows.

Comment: This seems to work fine for my purposes so I can cope with a little ambiguity in the library's implementation for now.  Many thanks for this.